Python replace period if it's the only value in column
How do I replace '.' in a dataframe if it's the only value in a cell without also replacing it if it's part of a decimal number?
Here's the dataframe



id




2.2222


.


.


3.2


1.0



I tried this but it removes all decimals
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['2.2222','.','.','3.2','1.0']})
df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace('.','',regex=False)

Unwanted result:



id




22222








32


10



This is the desired result:



id




2.2222








3.2


1.0




You can use the regexp ^\.$

You could use .loc to do the replace:
df.loc[df['id'] == '.', 'id'] = ''

